# Use gapi.client.request to consume cloud endpoints

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible to use the gapi.client.request to make REST calls to the api I developed using cloud endpoints? I tried and the it made a call to https://content.googleapis.com and not to my gae environment.

I noticed that when I use the http://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/ with my api as the base, it works in the way I'm trying to do in my app. I tried to check the code from explorer to see what it is doing but I couldn't get how to do it.

I'm trying to make the rest call so I don't need to load the the library when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to do it. I need to pass the root parameter when creating the request object.

```
gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/resource/v1/get',
    'root': 'http://localhost:8080/_ah/api'
  }).execute(function(response){
    // do something
  });
```